# Merge sort in Haskell

Tags: haskell, performance, mergesort

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to implement a few known algorithms in it.

I have implemented merge sort on strings. I am a bit disappointed with the
performance of my Haskell implementation compared to C and Java implementations.
On my machine (Ubuntu Linux, 1.8 GHz), C (gcc 4.3.3) sorts 1 000 000 strings in 1.85 s,
Java (Java SE 1.6.0_14) in 3.68 s, Haskell (GHC 6.8.2) in 25.89 s.
With larger input (10 000 000 strings), C takes 21.81 s, Java takes 59.68 s, Haskell
starts swapping and I preferred to stop the program after several minutes.

Since I am new to Haskell, I would be interested to know if my implementation can
be made more time / space efficient.

Thank you in advance for any hint
Giorgio

My implementation:

```
merge :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x < y
                        then x : (merge xs (y:ys))
                        else y : (merge (x:xs) ys)

mergeSort :: [String] -> [String]
mergeSort xs = if (l < 2)
                 then xs
                 else merge h t
               where l = length xs
                     n = l `div` 2
                     s = splitAt n xs
                     h = mergeSort (fst s)
                     t = mergeSort (snd s)
```

Comment: btw, what compilation flags did you use with GHC?

Comment: This isn't exactly an ideal implementation. You are continually traversing each sublist to find its length, and this is just unnecessary. See Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil version below for the more lazy and probably faster version.

Comment: @Axman6 - Can you supply a link to this algorithm? Or a citation?

Comment: You should use "if x <= y" rather than "if x < y" to create a stable sort (ie, equal objects remain in their original order)

Answer (score 18):

Try this version:

```
mergesort :: [String] -> [String]
mergesort = mergesort' . map wrap

mergesort' :: [[String]] -> [String]
mergesort' [] = []
mergesort' [xs] = xs
mergesort' xss = mergesort' (merge_pairs xss)

merge_pairs :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
merge_pairs [] = []
merge_pairs [xs] = [xs]
merge_pairs (xs:ys:xss) = merge xs ys : merge_pairs xss

merge :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs [] = xs
merge (x:xs) (y:ys)
 = if x > y
        then y : merge (x:xs)  ys
        else x : merge  xs    (y:ys)

wrap :: String -> [String]
wrap x = [x]
```

1. Bad idea is splitting list first. Instead of it just make list of one member lists. Haskell is lazy, it will be done in right time.
2. Then merge pairs of lists until you have only one list.

Comment: A version that is "stable" +1

Comment: This allocates a lot of memory compared to a quicksort so I doubt it's still used as a standard library function.

Comment: @egdmitry: Yep it was replaced 24/12/2009 by better but still merge sort implementation. So it was true when I originally answered the question. Anyway if you have any proof that quicksort allocates less memory or behave better please elaborate. And why you not look to the source code but guess?

Comment: I meant that a standard quicksort implementation allocates much less memory than your implementation given here. As for your last question — profiling standard sort function and your given implementation was enough for me to determine they are not the same without looking at the code.

Answer (score 14):

In Haskell, a string is a lazy list of characters and has the same overhead as any other list.  If I remember right from a talk I heard Simon Peyton Jones give in 2004, the space cost in GHC is 40 bytes per character.  For an apples-to-apples comparation you probably should be sorting [`Data.ByteString`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/bytestring/Data-ByteString.html), which is designed to give performance comparable to other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not sure whether ByteString is the same as String. As far as I know

    String :: [Char]

where Char is a unicode charactoer.
On the other hand, BytyString contains a string of Word8, i.e. of
bytes. Then I should make sure that my input is in an one-byte-per
character encoding, e.g. Latin1.
Otherwise, how does a ByteString handle multibyte characters when
evaluating the lexicographic ordering?

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string-0.3.5: "The utf8-string package provides operations for encoding UTF8 strings to Word8 lists and back, and for reading and writing UTF8 without truncation."

Answer (score 9):

Better way to split the list to avoid the issue CesarB points out:

```
split []             = ([], [])
split [x]            = ([x], [])
split (x : y : rest) = (x : xs, y : ys)
                       where (xs, ys) = split rest

mergeSort []  = []
mergeSort [x] = [x]
mergeSort xs  = merge (mergesort ys) (mergesort zs)
                where (ys, zs) = split xs
```

EDIT: Fixed.

Comment: @alexey_r: you have two errors in your code. one is that the "x : y : xs" pattern must come inside parentheses. the other is that the precedences of ":" and "$" make it that you give "split xs" to the function "x : fst"

Comment: @alexey_r: I think your code currently calculates "split xs" twice. better use (ys, zs) = split xs. or splitxs = split xs. so there's only one invocation of split

Comment: as a socialist I am bothered by the redundant dollar in "(mergesort $ ys)" :)

Comment: Changed that as well (despite not being a socialist :))

Comment: This implementation of split makes it hard (impossible) to create a stable sort algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but remember that lists are a sequential data structure. In particular, both `length xs` and `splitAt n xs` will take an amount of time proportional to the length of the list (`O(n)`).

In C and Java, you are most probably using arrays, which take constant time for both operations (`O(1)`).

Edit: answering your question on how to make it more efficient, you can use arrays in Haskell too.

Comment: But you probably don't want to for representing strings. Norman Ramsey is right: that's what `Data.ByteString` is for.

Comment: @alexey_r: I meant arrays for replacing [String], not for replacing String aka [Char] itself. Replacing String is a separate optimization.