# Haskell performance : Inversion count algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, haskell, optimization

I have decided to solve first programing assignment from Standford algorithm course https://class.coursera.org/algo-005 using Haskell. Despite I am very new to language I implemented it much faster than in c++.  I have 6+ years of work experience in c++ so it   impressed me a bit. But performance is disappointing: 0.19 sec (c++) vs 9.88 (haskell) version.
How can I improve performance of Haskell implementation so it can be comparable to c++?

Here is my code in Haskell

```
data SortedList = SortedList {
    inversionCount :: Int,
    list :: [Int]
} deriving (Show) 

--      first   list        accumulator
packm :: Int -> SortedList -> Int -> SortedList
packm x (SortedList count xs) add =  SortedList (count + add) (x:xs)

merge2 :: [Int] -> [Int] -> SortedList
merge2 [] xs = SortedList 0 xs
merge2 xs [] = SortedList 0 xs
merge2 xlist@(x:xs) ylist@(y:ys)
    | x < y = packm x (merge2 xs ylist) 0
    | otherwise = packm y (merge2 xlist ys) $ length xlist

countAndMerge :: SortedList -> SortedList -> SortedList
countAndMerge (SortedList lcount lxs) (SortedList rcount rxs) =
    let merged = merge2 lxs rxs
    in SortedList (lcount + rcount + inversionCount merged) $ list merged

mergesort :: [Int] -> SortedList
mergesort [] = SortedList 0 []
mergesort [x] = SortedList 0 [x]
mergesort xs =
    let leftsorted = mergesort $ take halfElements xs
        rightsorted = mergesort $ drop halfElements xs
    in countAndMerge leftsorted rightsorted
    where halfElements = length xs `div` 2

main = do 
    contents <- getContents
    let intlist = [ read x :: Int | x <- (lines contents) ]
    print $ inversionCount $ mergesort intlist
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling it?

Comment: What input list have you tried?

Comment: Two comments: First, since you are reading from a file, much of your time might be spent on file input.  You might be comparing Haskell I/O to C++ I/O more than the performance of the algorithms.  Second, since a C++ merge sort can be in-place, it is going to touch a lot less memory than a functional merge sort. An imperative merge-sort uses (2N cells). The functional mergsort uses Theta(N log N) cells.

Comment: Are you using linked lists in your C++ code as well?  Haskell lists are not arrays, they aren't meant for speed but for convenience, much like Python's lists.  Try switching to `Data.Vector` and see how far that gets you.  The only list specific features you use are pattern matching, prepending, `take`, `length`, and `drop`.  You can convert this code to use the equivalent `Data.Vector` functions pretty easily, although it means you'll be sacrificing the convenient pattern matching.  Nonetheless, you won't get anywhere near an accurate comparison between the two without it.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215432/merge-sort-in-haskell)

Comment: @bheklilr No. The idiomatic Haskell way is using lists, the idiomatic C++ way is using vectors. Comparing idiomatic to idiomatic is the only fair way to compare.

Comment: @n.m. When you're wanting to get two implementations to have comparable efficiencies (as OP wants to do), one of the first questions to ask is "what data structure is being used?".  Lists are great data structures for many, many tasks, but when you need to split, partition, and access elements, vectors win every time with O(1) performance instead of O(n).  I imagine you would also argue that the only way to compare Fibonacci implementations is if both are written in the idiomatic way in both languages? There are far more efficient ways to write it, and it's perfectly valid to compare them too.

Comment: I think that to compare languages one needs to ask not whether the data structures are similar, but whether the data structures occupy comparable niches in their respective language ecosystems. Otherwise the comparison is not between languages as living things, but between two implementation of some specific algorithm. Far less interesting.

Comment: @n.m. OP's specific question was "How can I improve performance of Haskell implementation so it can be comparable to c++?", which is not the same as "Why is my idiomatic Haskell implementation slower than my idiomatic C++ implementation?".  OP is not wanting to compare nuances in languages designs, but in this one, specific algorithm.

Comment: Make the inversion count field strict.  Avoid traversing the list so many times by, e.g., splitting it taking alternate elements.

Comment: @bheklilr Switching from lists to stateful arrays is one way to improve performance, but it's my least favourite one. I'd rather switch all the way to C++. There should be a way to boost performance while staying with lists, maybe not to the C++ levels but considerably. In this implementation processing time grows faster than it theoretically should. It looks more like quadratic, or worse. This can be fixed.

Comment: @n.m. I didn't say stateful arrays, I just said use `Data.Vector`.  You should be able to get a sizable speed boost by using contiguous memory without having cache misses at virtually every step.  There are algorithmic complexity problems with this implementation as well, I did not say there weren't, but my suggestion was to start by using a more efficient data structure that is almost a drop-in replacement for lists that is more similar to C++ arrays.  If I wrote a parser based on `String` and complained about performance, people would immediately suggest using `Text` instead.

Comment: @all 
Thanks for your attention. Here you can find my source code and input file.
https://github.com/capone212/algorithms/tree/master/w1 

I compile my program like: ghc --make mergeSort
And start like: time cat IntegerArray.txt | ./mergeSort

Right now I am going to try some of you ideas. I can say, that IO is not a bottleneck. It took several milliseconds to read and parse input from haskell.

Comment: @capone Oh - you forgot to compile with `-O2` to turn on optimisations - the first step in making your code fast is to tell the compiler that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem is that the asymptotic performance isn't right to begin with; it's O(n^2 * log n) rather than the optimal O(n * log n). The culprit is `merge2`:

```
    | otherwise = packm y (merge2 xlist ys) $ length xlist
```

`length xlist` is O(n). Supposing a random input list, we need to compute `length xlist` on about half of the `merge2` calls, thus making one level of merging O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

`otherwise = packm y (merge2 xlist ys) $ length xlist`

This computes length at every other step of the merge on the average. This makes the whole business quadratic.

If you track length of lists not by counting elements, but by passing the count down from the top level, you restore the O(N log N) behaviour. For a list of 100000 elements this means execution time goes down from 20 seconds to 0.45 second (on my machine with -O2).

Scaling it further up without changing the algorithm is problematic, because it currently runs in linear stack space, and cannot cope with 1 million elements with default RTS options. Change mergesort to a merge-adjacent-pairs version, it is likely to run much better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for right answer. I don't know who was the first, so I marked Andras version as a answer, because he has less reputation than you. Please, don't feel bad about it.